# Avoid failed cases in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am running `jmeter` to perform performance testing on a web application. The web application restricts the creation of the duplicate task. When I record that using `blazemeter` and run it with 100 threads, it shows that the task creation url is failed in the report, as it tries to create a task with the same name. How to avoid this?

Comment: You need to parameterized that on variable which is responsible to make the URL different and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you simply [cannot record and replay JMeter script without prior modifications](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script) as you need to perform correlation and parameterization.

In particular your case you need to identify the `task id`, most probably it is a parameter of a POST request and replace recorded hard-coded value with a [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will generate a random value, i.e.

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - for a random number in the given range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - for a random string from the given characters
- [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - creates a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like structure with a very high chance of being unique, i.e. `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`